# Android AlertDialog crashes with BadTokenException?

Tags: java, android

this is my first post so please bear with me.
I'm a high school developer and recently released an Android app on the play store. I'm using Crashlytics to capture exceptions, and for this some reason it throws this error.

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@1989547c is not valid; is your activity running?
```

It was reported specifically on the LG D855, Nexus 5, and the Huawei PLK AL10 occurring on versions 5.0, 5.0.2, 5.1.1 and 6.0.1. I've looked online, and have found that this occurs when an activity does not exist. This error occurs on the initial startup of the app.

The following is the code I use for an Alert Dialog which simply asks if the user wants to see a tutorial (y/n)

```
public void showTutorialDialog() {
    AlertDialog tutorialDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.tutorial_question_title)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage(R.string.tutorial_question)
            .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial_question_pos), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Take to tutorial
                    // Assume isn't backer for now..
                    finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, TutorialActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("from", "StartupActivity");
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial_question_neg), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // No tutorial, ask if they are a backer
                    showBackerDialog();
                }
            }).show();
```

Upon the initial start of the app, I load the users purchase details using IabHelper in a separate class. This class, called PurchaseRetriever, retrieves the content of users purchases asynchronously and stores it in an ArrayList. This is how my code works.

```
            if (mManager.isUserFirstTime()) {
                // Initialize purchase retriever.
                // The rest will be done when the observer reports that purchase data has been retrieved.
                mPurchases = PurchaseRetriever.getInstance(StartupActivity.this);
                mPurchases.addObserver(new FirstStartupObserver(this));
                StartupManager.FIRST = true;
                loadImageContent();
```

It runs using the Observer pattern, so when the purchase details are queried it calls the update() method in FirstStartupObserver, which then by a reference to StartupActivity, calls `startupActivity.showTutorialDialog();`where the error occurs.

I've tested it on multiple devices I and my friends own personally (Nexus 6, Nexus 5, Nexus 7 tablet, Samsung Galaxy Tab, various devices on Samsung Remote Lab) yet it works fine on my end...
Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Edit: Here is StartupActivity.

```
/**
 * Main startup activity. Determines which activity to launch.
 * Puts the user in one place or another depending on if they are a backer.
 */
public class StartupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StartupManager mManager;
    private ProgressBar bar;

    // --- Used if first time app loading to query purchase info
    private PurchaseRetriever mPurchases;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Used in either cases
        // If first time, displayed, if not, hidden//
        //hideNavBar();
        User.init(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);
        bar = (ProgressBar)this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mManager = new StartupManager(this);

        // Returns true if data was corrupt before
        if (mManager.isDataCorrupt()) {
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadImageContent();
            // Reset watch to default black
            // Internally starts NewMainActivity
            ErrorManager.fixCorruptData(bar, this);
        } else {
            // Stays true until user selects watch
            if (mManager.isUserFirstTime()) {
                // Initialize purchase retriever.
                // The rest will be done when the observer reports that purchase data has been retrieved.
                mPurchases = PurchaseRetriever.getInstance(StartupActivity.this);
                mPurchases.addObserver(new FirstStartupObserver(this));
                StartupManager.FIRST = true;
                loadImageContent();
            } else {
                // NOT first time starting app.
                mPurchases = PurchaseRetriever.getInstance(StartupActivity.this);
                mPurchases.addObserver(new AfterFirstStartupObserver(this));
                loadImageContent();
            }
        }


    }

    // Two main dialogs used
    public void showTutorialDialog() {
        AlertDialog tutorialDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.tutorial_question_title)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(R.string.tutorial_question)
                .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial_question_pos), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Take to tutorial
                        // Assume isn't backer for now..
                        finish();
                        Intent i = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, TutorialActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("from", "StartupActivity");
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial_question_neg), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // No tutorial, ask if they are a backer
                        showBackerDialog();
                    }
                }).show();

        tutorialDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tutorialDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    private void showBackerDialog() {
        // Show AlertDialog ask if they are kickstarter backer
        AlertDialog askDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.startup_dialog_title))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.startup_dialog_message))
                .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.startup_dialog_pos), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // User is a backer, take to watch chooser screen, then it takes to login screen
                        // Also look at Timer with TimerTask
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, WatchChooserActivity.class);
                                    i.putExtra("from", "StartupActivityBacker");
                                    startActivity(i);
                                } finally {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.startup_dialog_neg), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // User is not a backer, take to MainActivity

                        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, WatchChooserActivity.class);
                                    i.putExtra("from", "StartupActivityNonBacker");
                                    startActivity(i);
                                } finally {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
                }).show();

        askDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED);
        askDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

Here is the code for FirstStartupObserver.'

```
public class FirstStartupObserver implements Observer {
    private StartupActivity startupActivity;
    public FirstStartupObserver(StartupActivity startupActivity) {
        this.startupActivity = startupActivity;
    }

    // Called when the observable is done loading purchase detail
    // (Only called when user runs app first time)
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        // Set default first-time watch
        //  Query product data (the Watchfaces purchased in the form of a WatchFace object)
        PurchaseRetriever mPurchases = PurchaseRetriever.getInstance(startupActivity);
        if (mPurchases.hasSuccess()) {
            ArrayList<DynamicLoader.WatchFace> facesOwned = mPurchases.getPurchasedFaces();
            for (DynamicLoader.WatchFace f : facesOwned) {
                f.setPurchased(true);
            }
            // Check if coming from v1.4
            if (UpgradeManager.isUpgrading(startupActivity)) {
                // Then it calls the code below, but after the async task.
                String accessCode = UpgradeManager.getOldAccessCode(startupActivity);
                String accessToken = UpgradeManager.getOldAccessToken(startupActivity);
                UpgradeManager.migrateBacker(startupActivity, accessCode, accessToken);
            } else {
                // Ask if they want to see tutorial.
                // This is when the exception occurs!!!

                startupActivity.showTutorialDialog();

            }
            return;
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Showing fail dialog");
            DialogUtils.showIabFailDialog(startupActivity, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `showTutorialDialog ` method is in class which is extending  Activity or in normal java class?

Comment: showTutorialDialog() is a method in 'StartupActivity'. So when the purchases are queried, it would call the update() method in FirstStartupObserver' I store an instance of the StartupActivity in the FirstStartupObserver constructor here:  mPurchases.addObserver(new FirstStartupObserver(this)); Edit: Sorry trying to figure out how to format code...

Comment: post some of your code where you are calling showTutorialDialog().

Answer (score 0):

> token android.os.BinderProxy@1989547c is not valid; is your activity
>   running?

You are trying to load the `AlertDialog` too early, when the Activity doesn't exist! In my apps I load a little tutorial when the activity lifecycle is completed:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    ...
    ...
    ...

    showTutorialDialog();
}
```

Comment: This is the exact setup I have. Consider I have tested it on multiple devices and it doesn't crash, only one select few devices.

Comment: could you post the code before the execution of showTutorialDialog(), probably you have an exception that closes the app.

Comment: Yep I've updated the post with the two main classes. As you can see,                 mPurchases.addObserver(new FirstStartupObserver(this)) is called by the PurchaseRetriever class after the iab details have been queried. The update method is called then, where the showTutorialDialog() method is called via StartupActivity reference. There is something wrong but I just can't put my finger on why it is crashing for few users.

Answer (score 0):

> token android.os.BinderProxy@1989547c is not valid; is your activity
>   running?

This means that you're trying to show your popup while your activity is being destroyed or after it's destroyed.

You can check if your activity `isDestroyed` like below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 && !isDestroyed()) {
    showTutorialDialog();
}
```

If you're supporting below api 17 devices you can try to use `isFinishing` in else case. I did not test if it's working as expected. (If i'm wrong please correct me.)

```
else {
        if (!isFinishing()) { 
             showTutorialDialog();
         }
   }
```

Or for a quick fix you can surround with `try catch`

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by doing something in an `AsyncTask` or other background task which holds a reference to the `Activity` and tries to display the dialog when the work is done.  In this case, it sounds like your `FirstStartupObserver` is holding a reference to the activity and trying to show a dialog, but the activity may have been destroyed by the time `PurchaseRetriever` completes its work.

Don't try to test the activity state, and don't catch the `BadTokenException`.  That just masks the problem.  The simplest solution would be to cancel the `PurchaseRetriever` when the activity is paused.  If you want the background work to survive configuration changes like rotations but still be restricted to the user-perceived lifetime of the activity, do the work in a retained fragment.  Finally, if the background work should continue when the user navigates between activities or puts the app in the background, do the work in a `Service` and save the result where the activity can retrieve it.

Comment: I am not doing any background operations which references the activity.This is a really confusing problem.

Comment: @ProgrammingGorp Maybe not directly, but it sounds like your `PurchaseRetriever` is the likely culprit.  As you described it, it's a background operation followed by a call to an observer which holds a reference to the `Activity` and tries to show a dialog.  If the activity is paused while this is running, you'll get a `BadTokenException`.

Comment: Yeah, but it is the `FirstStartupObserver` is the one which holds the reference to the `StartupActivity` . While PurchaseRetriever does run asynchronously to fetch iab data, the call to showTutorialDialog() is run on the main ui thread.

Comment: @ProgrammingGorp The point is that by the time `PurchaseRetriever` completes its work, the activity that `FirstStartupObserver` holds a reference to might have been paused or destroyed.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense! What do you suggest I do? I still want to keep the Observer pattern I have here. Is it determined by the Android system when to pause the activity like this?

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering if I can confirm this suspicion. Is there a way I can reproduce this type of error on my end? (Activity paused and the dialog trying to popup)

Comment: Also the comment you made about retained fragments was brilliant. I found out that my app was crashed on low memory devices when the fragment gets recreated because I did not consider that.

Comment: @ProgrammingGorp You could add an artificial delay to the background work and try hitting the back or home key while it's running.

Comment: I did do that by using Thread.sleep() but it didn't seem to do anything, the dialog functioned and displayed like normal.

Comment: I tried some debug statements on the production app, and found isFinishing() to return true when this crash is caused.

Comment: @ProgrammingGorp I'm going to write a test app to try to nail down what I thought I knew.  But I'm pretty busy this week...

Comment: Thanks. I'll be here  :(

Comment: I'm trying to decipher what is going on and I found this problem to be similar to mine. http://blackriver.to/2012/08/android-annoying-exception-unable-to-add-window-is-your-activity-running/